# How do prepare multiplication for any table up to ten in python?

Tags: python

So this is a pretty basic program, all i need to do is take in put from the user and then make its multiplication table up to ten. The problem is how. So far i have tried using while loop and for loop but to no avail. Here is my code:

```
number = input("Please Enter a Number:")
range = 1
while range < 11:
print(number * range)
range += 1
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you have with this code (apart from the indentation)?

Comment: Hint: try two loops, one inside the other.
Hint 2: you can do `print(something, end=" ")` to not print a newline. 
Hint 3: `input()` returns a string, you can call `int()` on it to turn it into an integer

Comment: If you correct the formatting, and convert the number to int, it will work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Properly formatted multiplication table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415384/properly-formatted-multiplication-table)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to convert your number in integer.

Add this line after you defined your number:

```
number = int(number)
```

Also, the indentation is not correct, you have to indent the code in the while loop